# Discord bot is recalled because of virus

Tags: bots, discord, virus

I am making a discord bot using Java Discord API , I Just made a basic bot which just replies and gives no. of online members.But after 1 day of adding the bot to my server Discord gave me an error "***Discord is recalling this bot as this bot contains virus***" I am confused now what to do , I Searched for this on web but unable to find.
Here is the code for bot : [Discord Bot](https://github.com/ayushkarn739/BasicDiscordBot-JDA)

Comment: You published your token, which means that someone else likely used that token to run a malicious bot.  Don't publish your token.  It's a secret.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You published your token. Someone has already stolen your token and is running their own code, likely a virus, under your bot user.

Go to discord's website, into developer settings and revoke your current bot token to create a new token.

Do not commit this token anywhere publicly.